# Deleting Lines if there is a dot in the 5th Column

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file and I want to remove all the line if it has a dot in the 5th Column.

**Input File:**

```
sc2/80         20      .        A        C        80      PASS    N=2       F=5;U=4
sc2/60         55      .        G        .        72      PASS    N=2       F=5;U=4 
sc2/68         20      .        T        A        71      PASS    N=2       F=5;U=4 
sc2/10         24      .        T        .        31      PASS    N=2       F=5;U=4
sc2/40         59      .        T        .        31      PASS    N=2       F=5;U=4
sc2/24         24      .        A        G        38      PASS    N=2       F=5;U=4
```

**Expected Output:**

```
sc2/80         20      .        A        C        80      PASS    N=2       F=5;U=4
sc2/68         20      .        T        A        71      PASS    N=2       F=5;U=4
sc2/24         24      .        A        G        38      PASS    N=2       F=5;U=4
```

Note: The file has a size of 64G and it has 690,000,000 lines in it. Is there an efficient solution as it is quite a big dataset. I would prefer Awk and Sed as I am new in the field.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this

```
awk '{ if ( $5 != "." ) { print $0; } }' input_file.Txt > output_file.txt
```

This will test if 5th column is not a dot and display the line.

Comment: Shorter: `awk '$5 != "."' input_file.Txt > output_file.txt`

Answer (score 5):

With `grep`, assuming the columns are tab separated, here using the ksh93/zsh/bash `$'...'` quotes:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -v $'^\([^\t]*\t\)\{4\}\.\t'
```

If the columns are separated by any amount of blanks:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -vE '^([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){4}\.[[:blank:]]'
```

GNU `grep` is generally faster than `awk` (especially GNU `awk`) or `sed`. Setting the locale to C generally speeds things up as well.

Comment: Can you define faster? 1%, 10%, 100%, 1000%? For most cases I would prefer `awk`'s readibility.

Comment: @Bernhard, from -100% to +1000% depending on what you're doing and on what data and in what locale. The regex engine in GNU grep is very efficient. In this particular case it may or may not be more efficient, but as the question was about processing huge files where performance is important, it's worse giving it a try. It will most certainly be more efficient than the `sed` equivalent. I agree that if performance is not a concern, the awk one is a lot better.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '$5 != "."' your-big-file     # from manatwork's comment
```

or

```
sed -n '/^ *[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+\. /!p' your-big-file
```

The portable version from Stephane Chazelas's comment:

```
sed -n '/^ *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *\. /!p' your-big-file
```

The [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) version assumes the separator is a space, but you can adapt it.

**Performance:**

Namrata said (comment) that the `sed` script is faster than the `awk`one. [Stephane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94656/13999) thinks the `grep` equivalent may be even faster...

Comment: I have also provided a `sed` version. Please run both using `time awk '...' your-file` and `time sed '...' your-file` and let us know the timings... Cheers

Comment: Currently I ran it with a small dataset. With the small dataset with the sed command it took the least time. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Note that `x\+` is not portable. The portable equivalent is `x\{1,\}` or `xx*`